# Missing Header Menu in IE when website is hosted

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I am bedazzled and I can't find any resonable explanation to this situation.

I have been develloping a website for a month now. As I was going I was backing up my work

```
- website-bkp1
- website-bkp2
- etc...
```

since bkp1 I was testing the website locally on IE and Firefox and I was making sure everything was OK. I was also uploading it to my hosting site and also testing it on IE and Firefox.

Last night I uploaded website-bkp10 that works locally on both IE and Firefox to my hosting site. I tested the functionality and in Firefox everything is fine but in IE my site is missing header content menu!!

I uploaded back bkp1 and still in IE I am missing the header menu... I cannot explain any of this.

Any idea what might have gone wrong at the hosting site that is now screwing up IE behavior?

Thanks

Note: this is the website: [formationmtl](http://www.formationmtl.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this string:

`<!–[if gte IE 9]> <script type=”text/javascript”> Cufon.set(‘engine’, ‘canvas’); </script> <![endif]–>`

After this string:

`<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

In your html `<head>` tag.

Comment: how can I do #1? :)
I have updated my answer with the website

Comment: nvm, you don't need to clean cache.
You just added cufon? Google it's IE issues.

Comment: sorry I am new to this. What you see now is bkp1 which is basically the template I got from the Internet. I didn't add cufon I guess it was in it. I didn't really understand what you meant by GoOgle it's IE issues

Comment: Googled that for ya and edited my answer. That's your font javascript plugin issue (plugin name cufon). This issue appears in ie9 only.

Comment: So the question is, why was this working 2 days ago without this patch??